# Correcting number sequence using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to correct an auto incrementing sequence of numbers in a certain table column using T-SQL?

Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

```
 Id   Bar  Foo
  2     5    1 
  3     6    1
 21     7    1
 22    16    1
154    17    1
176    18    1
```

I would like to update rows with `Foo = 1` in a way that it continues the `Bar` column sequence starting from row with certain `Id` (in this case lets choose row with `Id = 21`) and applies it to all following rows based on the `Id` column order

The end result would be:

```
 Id   Bar  Foo
  2     5    1 
  3     6    1
 21     7    1
 22     8    1
154     9    1
176    10    1
```

For more context:

The table stores file data for a certain location (location Id is 'Foo' from example). Each row is one file and it has its file number (file number is 'Bar' from example).

File number is determent at file creation based on current largest file number for that location. Because of some error, file number skipped some ahead leaving a gap in file number order and I would like to fix that gap using T Sql.

Comment: When you say "auto incrementing", what **exactly** are you talking about? An identity column?

Comment: *lets choose row with `Id = 14`* ... there is no such row in the data provided

Comment: If you just want a dumb incrementing value that has no bearing on the data (if you can reset 16 to 8 and 17 to 9 and that has no impact, what is the point?), why not just generate this sequence when you query the data? ROW_NUMBER() can do that without even having a column you have to maintain. The problem with storing this meaningless data is that you have to reset it every time any row is changed.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos edited the post

Comment: Do not attempt to keep continuously increment numbers in a database table.
That's bound to fail - Like Aaron Bertrand wrote in his comment - Use ROW_NUMBER() instead.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree, unfortunatly this is a peace of beautiful legacy code that I can only maintain and not refactor or redesign.. I updated the post with more context

Comment: Why can't you create a view that fakes that column? And if this incrementing value is so important to the legacy code, why doesn't the legacy code already handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Id` is the field that determines row order you can use the following query to `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
    SELECT Id, Bar, 
           FIRST_VALUE(Bar) OVER (ORDER BY Id) + 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1 AS newBar
    FROM mytable
    WHERE Foo = 1 AND Id >= 21
)
UPDATE ToUPDATE
SET Bar = newBar
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/AQRQN73355)

As already mentioned in a comment, you can obtain the `Bar` value from a query like the one used by the `CTE`. So, there is no real need to persist such a value in a column of your table.